# For loop mishap

Tags: go, syntax-error

The issue here appears to be syntax, this is day 3 of coding in Go for me.  The for loop give me the red underline under for and the message says: "expected declaration found, 'for'"

Can someone explain to me why and/or where I went wrong?

```
func getAllWithTag(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Requests) {
    fmt.Println("Results with tag: *Tags)
}

var params = mux.Vars(r)

for _, tag := range tags {
  if *Tags == nil {
    Jason.NewEncoder(w).Encode("error: The tag parameter is required")
  }     
}
```

In short I am trying to make the tags a required field when searching but that part isn't important til I resolve this error.

Comment: The error most likely has to do with whatever code is just preceding the `for`. Please include that.

Comment: Just updated it

Comment: `fmt.Println("Results with tag: *Tags)` seems a double quote was missing

Comment: Semicolons aren't used in Go.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put for loops in the global scope (outside of any function). If you want code that runs automatically in that package before the program starts, put it inside of an `init` function.

```golang
func init() {
    for {...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but func init doesn't take arguments

Comment: If you need to use some function arguments, then you need to put that code inside that function. The problem seemed to be that your for loop was not in any function.